# How to tell RequiredJS to look for text.js plugin in custom directory?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'd like to put `text.js` plugin in custom directory and have a custom name, like: `/app/some/path/here/to/text-version.js`.

When I `require` something using `text!` RequireJS is trying to load `text.js` from url specified by `baseUrl` in the config.

How to tell RequireJS to look for the text.js plugin in specific **directory** with specific **name**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `text.js` library is AMD compliant (exports a `define` statement wrapping the functionality), you can use the full path in your module's `define` stub:

```
// yourmodule.js
define(['/app/some/path/here/to/text-version.js'], function(text) {
    // etc
});
```

Read more about AMD module definitions here: http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#amd

Otherwise you will need to shim the library in your main RequireJS configuration script:

```
// main.js
require.config({
  paths: {
    text: '/app/some/path/here/to/text-version.js'
  },

  shim: {
    text : {
      exports : 'text'
    }
  }
});

// yourmodule.js
define(['text'], function(text) {
    // etc
});
```

Read more about RequireJS shimming here: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim

Comment: I'm not sure how it can help me. Does shim override `text!` behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered that although RequireJS auto-loads in the plugin, but it essentially calls `require('text', function (text) { /* ... */ })`. This means that configuring the path to any RequireJS plugin is actually remarkably easy -- just change the path in `require.config()`.

```
/**
 * main.js
 */
require.config({
    baseUrl: '/lib/js/',

    paths: {
        text: 'require/plugins/text'
    }
});
```

Now when you need the plugin in a module, e.g.

```
/**
 * myModule.js
 */
define([ 'text!/lib/css/stylesheet.css' ], function () {
    // ...
});
```

RequireJS will figure out to load the text plugin at `/lib/js/require/plugins/text.js`.